# Converting currency string into NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to convert some currency string (e.g., $25,000) into NSDecimalNumber using the following code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[currencyFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:TRUE];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

// textField.text is some currency string (e.g., $25,000)
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [currencyFormatter numberFromString:textField.text];
```

The compiler is complaining about the resulting type of currencyFormatter, is NSNumber instead of NSDecimalNumber but I'm setting this here:

```
[currencyFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumber:TRUE];
```

So I'm lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDecimalNumber` is a subclass of `NSNumber`. The `numberFromString:` method of `NSNumberFormatter` is declared to return `NSNumber*`, so you need to add a cast:

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = (NSDecimalNumber*)[currencyFormatter numberFromString:textField.text];
```

Since you have set the behavior to produce decimal numbers, this will work correctly.

Comment: Thank you dasblinkenlight, couldn't be more obvious.